# How to show that : $4(-1)^nL_n^2+L_{4n}-L_n^4=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, golden-ratio, lucas-numbers

How can we prove that:
$$4(-1)^nL_n^2+L_{4n}-L_n^4=2$$

Where $L_n$ is [Lucas number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number)

We got $L_n=\phi^n+(-\phi)^{-n}$

$4(-1)^nL_n^2=8(-1)^n\phi^{2n}+8$

$L_{4n}=\phi^{4n}+(-\phi)^{-4n}$

$L_n^4=4\phi^{4n}+4(-1)^n\phi^{2n}+4$

$$8(-1)^n\phi^{2n}+8+\phi^{4n}+(\phi)^{-4n}-4\phi^{4n}-4(-1)^n\phi^{2n}-4=2$$

$$3\phi^{4n}-4(-1)^n\phi^{2n}-\phi^{-4n}=2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $4(-1)^nL_n^2=8(-1)^n\phi^{2n}+8$
>
> $L_n^4=4\phi^{4n}+4(-1)^n\phi^{2n}+4$

These are incorrect.

We have
$$\begin{align}4(-1)^nL_n^2&=4(-1)^n(\phi^n+(-\phi)^{-n})^2
\\\\&=4(-1)^n(\phi^{2n}+2\phi^n(-\phi)^{-n}+(-\phi)^{-2n})
\\\\&=4(-1)^n(\phi^{2n}+2(-1)^n+\phi^{-2n})
\\\\&=4(-1)^n\phi^{2n}+8+4(-1)^n\phi^{-2n}
\\\\&=4(-1)^n\phi^{2n}+4(-1)^n\phi^{-2n}+8\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}L_n^4&=(L_n^2)^2
\\\\&=(\phi^{2n}+2(-1)^n+\phi^{-2n})^2
\\\\&=\phi^{4n}+4+\phi^{-4n}+4(-1)^n\phi^{2n}+2+4(-1)^n\phi^{-2n}
\\\\&=\phi^{4n}+\phi^{-4n}+4(-1)^n\phi^{2n}+4(-1)^n\phi^{-2n}+6\end{align}$$

It follows from these that
$$\begin{align}&4(-1)^nL_n^2+L_{4n}-L_n^4
\\\\&=4(-1)^n\phi^{2n}+4(-1)^n\phi^{-2n}+8+(\phi^{4n}+\phi^{-4n})
\\&\qquad\qquad -(\phi^{4n}+\phi^{-4n}+4(-1)^n\phi^{2n}+4(-1)^n\phi^{-2n}+6)
\\\\&=8-6
\\\\&=2\end{align}$$